# Короткая инструкция для относителных путей

Tags: linux, freebsd

При использовании относительных путей например `cd ./../../../..` хочется использовать какой нибудь сокращенный эквивалент этой команды, что то похожее на  `..\4` .

Может в POSIX системах есть, что то похожее на это ?

Comment: совет от «опытных собаководов»: лучше не пользоваться командой *cd* в интерактивной оболочке. ну, если **действительно** необходимо сменить текущий каталог (не часто встречающаяся ситуация), то лучше использовать связку *pushd/popd/dirs*. предупреждая вопрос: лучше указывать в аргументах полные, а не относительные пути («просто имя файла в текущем каталоге» — это частный случай относительного пути). прирост производительности и удобство ощутите, если будете использовать данную рекомендацию в комплексе с историей команд оболочки и прочими «плюшками», доступными от readline (или аналога).

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сами назначить алиасы, например такие:

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."
alias ....="cd ../../.."
alias .....="cd ../../../.."
alias ......="cd ../../../../.."
```

Или такие:

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ..2="cd ../.."
alias ..3="cd ../../.."
alias ..4="cd ../../../.."
alias ..5="cd ../../../../.."
```

Answer (score 3):

поступил вот так.

написал скрипт на баше

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$1" ]; do
  i=$(($i + 1))
  str=$str"../"
done

echo $str
```

и вот так его вызываю:

```
cd `имя_скрипта 7`
```

7 - это количество директорий на которые нужно вернутся.

если кто то может улучшить этот скрипт то буду этому рад

_____________ 17.10.2017 ______________

скрипт был усовершенствован до такого вида

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$1" ]; do
  i=$(($i + 1))
  ss=$ss"../"
done

cd $ss

unset ss
```

затем создаем вот такой алиас

```
alias cdn='. имя_скрипта '
```

и теперь его можно вызывать вот так:

cdn 6

цыфра в конце это количество директорий на которые необходимо вернутся

Comment: дополнительно вы можете сделать алиас `cd` который будет вызывать ваш скрипт, который уже будет вызывать оригинальный cd с доработанным путем

Comment: Можно придумать какой-нибудь ``xcd() { cd `имя_скрипта $1`; }`` и вызывать как `xcd 7`

Comment: @Mike точно, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Зачем внешний *cd* да ещё с вызовом интерпретатора? Вызывайте *cd* прямо из скрипта.

Comment: @0andriy из скрипта он меняет текущую директорию только именно в вызванном скрипте, а не в родительском.

Comment: @perfect, вот вам и задача на подумать, как добиться желаемого (подсказка: это возможно).

Comment: @0andriy исправил, спасибо за подсказку